# Alternative to pandas.read_html where ulr is not unique?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, html-table

I want to access data from an html table from the section "ERGEBNIS" with `python 3.7.`
The problem is, that the results for each combination of the drop down values are only shown after clicking on submit. This does however not change the url, so that I have no idea how I can access the results table after updating the input values of the drop downs.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

browser.get('https://daten.ktbl.de/feldarbeit/entry.html')

#Fix values of the drop down fields:

fertilizer = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("hgId"))
fertilizer.select_by_value("2") 

fertilizer = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("gId"))
fertilizer.select_by_value("193") 

fertilizer = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("avId"))
fertilizer.select_by_value("383")  

fertilizer = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("hofID"))
fertilizer.select_by_value("2") 

fertilizer = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("flaecheID"))
fertilizer.select_by_value("5") 

fertilizer= Select(browser.find_element_by_name("mengeID"))
fertilizer.select_by_value("60") 


# Submit changes to show the results of this particular combination of values

button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
button.click()
```

Submitting the changes does, however, not change the url, so that I don't know how I can access the results (here "ERGEBINS") table.

Otherwise my approach would have been to use pd.read_html somehow like this:

```
...

url = browser.current_url
time.sleep(1)
df_list = pd.read_html(url, match = "Dieselbedarf")
```

But since the url isn't unique for each result, this doesn't make sense. Same issue would be with BeautifulSoup, or at least I don't understand how I can do it without a unique url..

Any ideas how I can access the html table otherwise?

EDIT: The answer of @bink1time could solve my problem how to access the table without the url, but via the raw HTML string:

```
html_source = browser.page_source
df_list = pd.read_html(html_source, match = "Dieselbedarf")
```

Comment: you need to scrap table data inside `ERGEBNIS` based on `AUSWAHL` slection?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment, bink1time has answered my question perfectly already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably just get the html source:

```
html_source = browser.page_source
```

According to the docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html
read_html takes a URL, a file-like object, or a raw string containing HTML.
In this case you pass the raw string.

```
html_source = browser.page_source
df_list = pd.read_html(html_source, match = "Dieselbedarf")
```

Just a note you don't need to sleep.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! I had considered using the html source code but I was assuming that this would just give me the string of the unedited start page without the changes in the drop downs. Next time I'll try instead of assume...