# Stale Element Reference Exception when moving backwards through browser, even after refresh

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I am trying to make a scraper that will go through a bunch of links, export the guide as a PDF, and loop through all the guides that are in the parent folder. It works fine going in, ,but when I try to go backwards, it throws stale exceptions, even when I make sure to refresh the elements in the code, or refresh the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, bs4

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('MYURL')
loginElem = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
loginElem.send_keys('LOGIN')
pwdElem = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
pwdElem.send_keys('PASSWORD')
pwdElem.submit()
time.sleep(3)
category = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('title')
for i in category:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    guide = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('cell')
    for j in guide:
        j.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="html.parser")
        guidetitle = soup.find_all(id='guide-intro-title')
        print(guidetitle)
        browser.find_element_by_link_text('Options').click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Download PDF').click()
        browser.find_element_by_id('download').click()
        browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-2)")
        print("went back")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("waited")
        guide = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('thumb')
        print("refreshed elements")
    print("made it to outer loop")
```

This happens if I both use a script to move the browser back, or the driver.back() method. I can see that it makes it back to the child directory, then waits, and refreshes the elements. But, then it can't seem to load the new element to go into the next guide. I found a similar questions here on SO but someone just provided code tailored to the problem instead of explaining so I am still confused.

I also know about using waitdriver but I am just using sleep now since I don't fully understand the EC wait conditions. In any case, increasing the sleep time doesn't fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stale Element Reference Exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference) occurs upon page refresh because of an element UUID change in the DOM.
**How to avoid it:** Always try to search for an element right before interaction.

In your code, you searched for cells, found them and stored them in `guide`. So now, `guide` has a list of selenium UUIDs. But then, you are making a loop to go through the list, and upon each refresh (that happens when you do back I believe), cell's UUID changes, so old ones that you have stored are no longer attached to the DOM. When trying to interact with them, Selenium cannot find them in the DOM and throws this exception.

Instead of looping through `guide` your way, try re-find element every time, like:

```
guide = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('cell')
for j in range(len(guide)):
    browser.find_elements_by_class_name('cell')[j].click()
```

Note, it looks like `category` might have a similar problem, so try applying this solution to `category` as well.

Hope this helps. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60430007/7746992) is a similar issue and a solution.

Comment: So, when I do ``` guide = browser.xxx.('thumb') ``` the second time, once I'm back on the page, why doesn't that refresh the element with the new one on the page? It should generate that from the current page, right? I was thinking this should populate with the new elements.

Comment: For 'thumb' yes, correct (at least it should, hard to say without the page and error message), but not for `browser.find_elements_by_class_name('cell')`. It is outside the loop, and is found once, before you `went back`.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for clearing that up! It makes a lot more sense, I forgot it's not good practice to update list elements from inside a loop of that list.